# In terraform, is it possible to only add an optional resource argument if a particular variable is set

Tags: terraform, rancher

On my concrete example:

I want to create a rancher environment resource with preconfigured members. But the number of members is supposed to be depending on a variable list. I'd imaging something like

```tf
resource "rancher_environment" "renv" {
  name = "renv"
  project_template_id = "atmplid"

  member {
    count = "${length(var.memberlist)}"
    external_id = "${var.memberlist[count.index]}"
    external_id_type = "exttype"
    role = "owner"
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work. Is there a trick to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

You can use null_resource for this. Try this

```
resource "null_resource" "memberlist" {
    count = "${length(var.memberlist)}"
    triggers {
        external_id = "${var.memberlist[count.index]}"
        external_id_type = "exttype"
        role = "owner"
    }
}

resource "rancher_environment" "renv" {
    name = "renv"
    project_template_id = "atmplid"

    member = ["${null_resource.memberlist.*.triggers}"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At long last, Terraform has just released v0.12.0-alpha1, which contains [a more elegant way of solving this exact problem](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7034#issuecomment-433511035).